# Как отправить POST запрос с параметрами?

Tags: python, парсер, post, form, requests

Хочу спарсить ссылки на гугл миты из сайта своего универа.

Как отправить POST запрос на [страницу](https://dekanat.nung.edu.ua/cgi-bin/timetable.cgi?n=700)?

Нужно ввести группу, в моем случае "КІ-19-1", и в ответ получить HTML код с расписанием.

Дальше я уже справлюсь с BS4.

Что-то пробовал написать, но в ответ нет ответа от формы:

```
import requests
import fake_useragent
link = "https://dekanat.nung.edu.ua/cgi-bin/timetable.cgi/post"
pload = {'group':'КІ-19-1'}
user_agent = {
    "User_Agent":fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
}
r = requests.post(link,params=pload,headers = user_agent)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: уберите user_agent и будет работать

Comment: @entithat , убрал. Ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Адрес, с которого приходят данные, немного отличается. Попробуйте:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://dekanat.nung.edu.ua/cgi-bin/timetable.cgi?n=700'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
    'faculty': '0',
    'teacher': '',
    'group': 'ʲ-19-1',
    'sdate': '',
    'edate': '' ,
    'n': '700'
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

таблицы в супе:

```
tables = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-md-6')
for table in tables[1:]:
    print(table.find('h4').text)
```

выведет:

```
04.06.2021 П'ятниця
07.06.2021 Понеділок
08.06.2021 Вівторок
09.06.2021 Середа
11.06.2021 П'ятниця
```

попробуйте искать ссылки как-то так:

```
table.find('a')['href']
```

---

UPD обратите внимание: ваша группа передается как `'group': 'ʲ-19-1'`, а не 'КІ-19-1' (пока не выяснил связи, но - как есть)